# Cómo solucionar error 104 al consultar el servicio web de face

Tags: webservice, soap, soapui

Resulta que tengo a la hora de mandar el Request con el método de Enviar Factura, en la respuesta me da un código de error 104. Supuestamente lo estoy probando con SoapUI y a la hora de hacer la solicitud reemplazo los ? por mis valores, pero al ejecutar me da el error 104, la petición SOAP no está bien construida: no se encuentra el SOAP Header

[image: Schema del método del servicio web]

[image: Schema del servicio web sustituido con mis datos]

[image: Respuesta del servicio web con código de error]

Que me falta para que funcione bien
Gracias

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque esta intentado acceder a un recurso externo. La ayuda será de quien realizó el Servicio Web

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Falta configurar WS-Security. El [Manual de Uso de Servicios -
facturasspp](https://administracionelectronica.gob.es/ctt/resources/Soluciones/334/Descargas/servicio-web-facturasspp.pdf?idIniciativa=334&idElemento=5052) dice:

> Las peticiones deben ir firmadas
> tal y como se indica en el apartado Implementación o con un formato válido de WS-Security 1.0
> X.509 Token Profile.

El mismo manual muestra una petición de ejemplo que incluye un extenso contenido de la etiqueta `<soapenv:Header>` y que en las imágenes de la pregunta se observa que está vacía. También menciona cómo obtener un archivo PEM (que debería incluir una llave pública y una llave privada) para firmar las peticiones:

> Para poder utilizar los servicios web de FACe deberá darse de alta previamente en el portal
> web de FACe, en el menú de Integradores – Gestión de Certificados
> (https://face.gob.es/es/proveedores), donde informará del PEM del certificado con el que firmará las
> llamadas a los servicios web.

De la petición de ejemplo del manual se puede deducir la siguiente configuración para la Outgoing WS-Security Configuration de SoapUI:

- Must Undestand: ✅ (chequeado)
- Key Identifier Type: `Binary Security Token`
- Signature Algorithm: `http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsasha1`
- Signature Canonicalization: `http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-excc14n#`
- Digest algorithm: `http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1`

Otros enlaces útiles:

1. [Área Descargas - FACe - Punto General de Entrada de Facturas Electrónicas de la AGE](https://administracionelectronica.gob.es/ctt/face/descargas). En la sección «Documentación para integradores» se encuentra el manual mencionado arriba, manuales de otros servicios e información de los certificados de los servicios web de pruebas y producción.
2. [WS-Security Settings](https://www.soapui.org/docs/security-testing/ws-security-settings/) de SoapUI (inglés).
3. [KeyStore Explorer](https://keystore-explorer.org/index.html). Herramienta para gestionar keystores de Java, como la que se necesita configurar en la Outgoing WS-Security Configuration de SoapUI.

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero tengo una duda tanto para el entorno de pruebas como para el de producción me tengo que dar de alta en la web de face. Entiendo que para el entorno de producción sí ¿pero para el entorno de pruebas también?

Comment: @SergioDavidPerezAcosta, el manual no dice que no, entonces creo que sí sería necesario. Si la respuesta te ayudó considera votarla a favor o marcarla como aceptada. Ver: [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

a mi también me ha servido tu respuesta, aun que hay varias cosillas de esa cabecera de ejemplo que no estoy seguro de como tengo que rellenarlas.

- Lo primero que se rellena es el BinarySecurityToken que se llena con
  el certificado digital (ese lo tengo claro)
- Luego hay otro campo que se podría tener que rellenar que es el
  SignedInfo que dentro tiene el campo DigestValue con un valor ya
  relleno, y no se si este seria necesario el modificarlo.
- y por ultimo el campo SignatureValue que tengo claro que tengo que
  rellenar, pero no se con que.

entiendo que a través de algún algoritmo con el que consigo dichos valores, pero no termino de enterarme bien.

Gracias y un saludo!

Comment: No utilizes la sección de respuestas para exponer dudas, puedes formular una pregunta en su lugar