# Error 100 Petición SOAP a FACe desde SoapUI

Tags: soapui

Estoy desarrollando un módulo para subir facturas al FACe.
Estoy dado de alta como integrador en FACe (Stagging) para hacer pruebas.
Estoy usando SoapUI 5.7.0

Tengo este XML en SOAPUI:

---

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="https://webservice.face.gob.es">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <web:enviarFactura>
         <request>
            <!--You may enter the following 3 items in any order-->
            <correo>xxxx@xxxx.xxx</correo>
            <factura>
               <factura>PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiPz48ZmU6RmFjdHVyYWUgeG1s ... JlQ3JlZGl0ZWQ+PC9JbnN0YWxsbWVudD48L1BheW1lbnREZXRhaWxzPjwvSW52b2ljZT48L0ludm9pY2VzPjwvZmU6RmFjdHVyYWU+</factura>
               <nombre>322-023.xml</nombre>
               <mime>application/xml</mime>
            </factura>
            <anexos>
               <anexo>
                  <anexo>JVBERi0xLjcKJcOiw6PDj8OTCjEgMCBvYmoKPDwvVHlwZS9TaWcvRmlsdGVyL0Fkb2JlLlBQS0x ... 5aw4LClcKme8OsLiMRCmVuZHN0cmVhbQplbmRvYmoKc3RhcnR4cmVmCjE2NDE3MQolJUVPRgo=</anexo>
                  <nombre>322-023.pdf</nombre>
                  <mime>application/pdf</mime>
               </anexo>
            </anexos>
         </request>
      </web:enviarFactura>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

---

La Factura registrada en base64 en el XML, ha sido validada previamente (el xsig) usando:

https://face.gob.es/es/facturas/validar-visualizar-facturas

y la da como correcta, tanto el XML como la firma. El PDF registrado en base64 también está firmado con el mismo certificado, y Adobe Reader valida la firma del PDF sin problemas.

He registrado el certificado en SoapUI para firmar la petición SOAP y configurado la Firma para mensajes salientes:

[image]

tal como he visto en el manual, y aún así, la solicitud enviada desde SOAPUI, contesta con:

Error 100, la Firma de la Petición SOAP no es válida.

He buscado en internet qué podría estar pasando y he encontrado este enlace:
[Cómo solucionar error 104 al consultar el servicio web de face](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/416428/c%C3%B3mo-solucionar-error-104-al-consultar-el-servicio-web-de-face) justamente aquí en StackOverflow, pero veo que los parámetros que tengo registrados son los mismos que allí se indica ...

Entiendo que no se está quejando de los Datos del XML, sino de la Firma OASIS Binary Token de la petición SOAP. Supongo que tendré mal configurado algo más, porque es muuuuy raro que SoapUI genere mal una firma para una petición SOAP.

***Estas son las cabeceras y el XML que SoapUI envia al FACe una vez firmada la petición SOAP tal como he mostrado:***

**Sat May 06 14:35:27 CEST 2023: DEBUG: http-outgoing >>
POST /facturasspp2 HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: "https://webservice.face.gob.es#enviarFactura"
Content-Length: 306316
Host: se-face-webservice.redsara.es
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.5 (Java/16.0.1)**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="https://webservice.face.gob.es">
   <soapenv:Header><wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"><wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509PKIPathv1" wsu:Id="X509-0811B7244EC4BEE634168337652772198">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</wsse:BinarySecurityToken><ds:Signature Id="SIG-0811B7244EC4BEE6341683376527723102" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><ds:SignedInfo><ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"><ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="soapenv web" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/></ds:CanonicalizationMethod><ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/><ds:Reference URI="#id-0811B7244EC4BEE6341683376527722101"><ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"><ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="web" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/></ds:Transform></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/><ds:DigestValue>EkVIREeE1HxPR/AHqXOx4uxYAQs=</ds:DigestValue></ds:Reference></ds:SignedInfo><ds:SignatureValue>Jbo4Ax/a8jitADe2KAB0yCEo6lHwow3ykNkyXeyCeY0TAZBemB19/f7PapzvdDfNEbWZfBoK6n3kTpPW7Fufwu+w7vtZ5u48mVTzLQ6VatqLeCr5huRd9Gd1HVs0g1Fy70WKkwlgj3hK9aoxvYp8yzEbYJOO22Bg1MzsQK13HxtJ4UxzQ/gJR+8WDKLMQie7Gs48UBJ5xjn9IRbW9NXngGZkQKpkI+HFFw+92Np1bLH5V/2q33RgFryQCVI8BX8nk77LKxwCrIVp4nc5vdLhKKUAIJg3qVwM4j8oMw9C5r2m4FNE6JbEnyi/mqfK+zfO1Whf6/Gr5tRzOMEv2atc6Q==</ds:SignatureValue><ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-0811B7244EC4BEE634168337652772199"><wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsse11:TokenType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509PKIPathv1" wsu:Id="STR-0811B7244EC4BEE6341683376527721100" xmlns:wsse11="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.1.xsd"><wsse:Reference URI="#X509-0811B7244EC4BEE634168337652772198" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509PKIPathv1"/></wsse:SecurityTokenReference></ds:KeyInfo></ds:Signature></wsse:Security></soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body wsu:Id="id-0811B7244EC4BEE6341683376527722101" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
      <web:enviarFactura>
         <request>
            <!--You may enter the following 3 items in any order-->
            <correo>xxxxxx@xxxxxxxx.xxx</correo>
            <factura>
               <!--You may enter the following 3 items in any order-->
               <factura>PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLT ... PC9JbnN0YWxsbWVudD48L1BheW1lbnREZXRhaWxzPjwvSW52b2ljZT48L0ludm9pY2VzPjwvZmU6RmFjdHVyYWU+</factura>
               <nombre>322-023.xml</nombre>
               <mime>application/xml</mime>
            </factura>
            <anexos>
               <anexo>
                  <anexo>JVBERi0xLjcKJcOiw6PDj8OTCjEgMCBvYmoKPDwvVHlwZ ... mVhbQplbmRvYmoKc3RhcnR4cmVmCjE2NDE3MQolJUVPRgo=</anexo>
                  <nombre>322-023.pdf</nombre>
                  <mime>application/pdf</mime>
               </anexo>
            </anexos>
         </request>
      </web:enviarFactura>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

¿ Sabría alguien decirme qué podría tener mal o porqué se puede dar este error del FACe ?

Muchas Gracias.

Comment: El token y otros datos sensibles no deberían estar públicos en tu pregunta :/

Answer (score 0):

Me ha funcionado añadiendo el Namespace "http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" en la parte de abajo "Parts". Asegurarte que están bien puestos el keystore y truststore, check en "Use single certificate for signing"